# Can the text description at the lower left of the configurator be changed to show nothing?

Tags: roomle

At the lower left hand side of the Configurator screen there is Text that is driven from the Catalogue name and the name of the ROOT component, is there anyway of removing the text that appears from the ROOT Component? Ideally I want this is only show the Catalogue name [image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no native way of doing this in the standard implementation. You could delete the database label using CSV import (RuAd won't accept empty label field via UI):

```
"component_id","label_de","label_en"
"your_component_id","",""
```

I also tried using whitespace as a database label - see https://emptycharacter.com/, which works, but the catalogue label is not "promoted" to the place of the component label. Also it might not work as expected when pricing is used.

There is a pending update on 2021-03-20 on this article, should you have interest in more details on how this works: https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/200_110_advancedpartlist.html#where-are-component-labels-used